# Requests.get gives error Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException

Tags: sharepoint, python-3.5

I am calling sharepoint from my python requests.get code to pull sharepoint list items. However i am getting below error.

{"odata.error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The expression \"web/lists/GetByTitle(Useful Links)/items\" is not valid."}}}

This works fine when i call equivalent code from my angular code.

I tried to encode the url as it has spaces, brackets but it did not help.
i verified the url works fine by testing it from angular code and also postman tool.

```
@app.route('/getList',methods=['GET'])
def getList():
    try:        
        api_token = request.args.get('api_token', '')
        headers = {'Accept': 'application/json; odata=nometadata',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer {0}'.format(api_token)}

        api_url = '//<my company name>.sharepoint.com/teams/EIMGDS/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle(Useful Links)/items'
        response = requests.get("https:"+urllib.parse.quote(api_url),params={},headers=headers, verify=False)
        return response.text

    except Exception as ex:
        return jsonify({'message' : 'Error in Get List', 'detailedMessage': traceback.format_exc()}), 500
```

### Expected result:

JSON having the sharepoint list details

### Actual result:

{"odata.error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The expression \"web/lists/GetByTitle(Useful Links)/items\" is not valid."}}}